# TypeScript checking front-end template files

Tags: typescript, webpack, handlebars.js

I am new to TypeScript and loved it. 
Currently, using Webpack + TypeScript + Handlebars and getting below error message:

```
ERROR in ./src/apps/router/routes.ts
(6,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../templates/homeTpl.handlebars'.

ERROR in ./src/apps/router/routes.ts
(9,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../templates/aboutTpl.handlebars'.
```

I have installed `"@types/handlebars": "^4.0.31"`, in package.json and `"handlebars": "registry:dt/handlebars#4.0.5+20160804082238"`, in typings.json

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true
  },
"include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

also my webpack.config.js includes

```
...

  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: ["", ".ts", ".js"]
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'ts-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.handlebars?$/i,
      loader: 'handlebars-loader'
    }]
  }
...
```

I tried a lot but not able to figure out what is going wrong! https://github.com/Protocore-UI/protocore-typescript-edition.
Well, when I am excluding TypeScript and use ES6 with Webpack its working fine https://github.com/Protocore-UI/protocore-webpack-edition

Comment: Also added the comments on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5151

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5151#issuecomment-255478745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by just adding require declaration :

```
declare function require(module: string): any;
let HomeTemplate = require('../templates/homeTpl.handlebars');
```

Visit https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5151 for more information